# Elasticsearch path.data multiple disks, adding more

Tags: elasticsearch

When I originally set up my Elasticsearch cluster, it was recommended to "stripe" the data across multiple disks thusly:

> path.data: [ /disk1, /disk2, /disk3 ]

Which I did prevously, and has worked fine, but now I need to add more space (more disks), which I plan to do like this:

> path.data: [ /disk1, /disk2, /disk3, /disk4, /disk5 ]

I have not been able to find any authoritative reference that indicates how the data will be re-balanced (or not). It seems that the behavior has changed somewhat over the years/versions, so googling has been difficult.
All the docs say about it is: "path.data settings can be set to multiple paths, in which case all paths will be used to store data" which is rather vague.

I am running Elasticsearch 5.6.

I would like to understand what will happen when disks 1,2,3 are above the 85% "low watermark" (but not yet at the high 90% mark), and I introduce 2 new disks to the mix. Will new indices go to the 2 new disks only?

The docs say: "ES will not allocate new shards to nodes once they have more than 85% disk used". Does this mean the whole node, or just the disks that are at 85% on that node?

My indices are daily logging data, and are pruned with Curator every N days, so I imagine at some point, things will even out but may take a while. Is there any way to proactively relocate shards to a different disk or should I just let it self-balance over time?

Comment: Did you ever found an answer to your inquires? I am facing the same issues...

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple disks (via data paths) is not STRIPING. Data is distributed across disks by shards count and not disk space usage. Even if a single disk goes past watermark, the node will get affected. So adding new disks to data path won't distribute data to new disks.

To use data striping use atleast RAID0 or other options as per your data safety requirement.

REFER [Data storage architecture](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-design-your-elasticsearch-data-storage-architecture-for-scale)